# Using auth_user, email is saved under last_name column

Tags: python, django, authentication, unique, models

I'm using the Django provided user model. Everything worked fine but after a single change where I tried to make the `email` field `unique`.

my `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')
    User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

the line of code I added to `forms.py` in order to make the email field `unique` is:

```
User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True
```

my `views.py`:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()
            private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
                public_exponent=65537,
                key_size=4096,
                backend=default_backend()
            )
            public_key = private_key.public_key()
            pem_private_key = private_key.private_bytes(
                encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
                format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
                encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
            )
            user.profile.public_key = public_key.public_bytes(
                encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
                format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
            )
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1').encode()
            user.profile.salt = os.urandom(16)
            kdf = Scrypt(
                salt=user.profile.salt,
                length=32,
                n=2 ** 20,
                r=8,
                p=1,
                backend=default_backend()
            )
            key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(raw_password))
            f = Fernet(key)
            user.profile.encrypted_private_key = f.encrypt(pem_private_key)
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Activate Your MySite Account'
            message = render_to_string('accounts/account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            user.email_user(subject, message)
            return redirect('account_activation_sent')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

here is where I register the user, I have also added a profile model where I create some keypairs for the user all of which worked as expected. I also have an email activation sent in order to activate the user.

my `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    encrypted_private_key = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    public_key = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    salt = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

Here I create the User Profile using signals.

my html file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Sign up</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
      <p>
        {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
        {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
          <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
        {% endif %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
      </p>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

When I added that line of code to make the `email` field in `auth_user` `unique` I had to do `makemigrations` and then `migrate`. The `email` field did become `unique` and I get an error code when I try to register with an existing email. But when observing the database I noticed that the email is saved on the `last_name` column which is really weird.

I tried to reverse the situation by removing that line of code and applying the migrations again but the same thing happens again.

Everything worked as expected before I made the email field unique.

Comment: I find it very weird that you write this `User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True` under the form class. I think it is probably better to patch it in the `models.py` file, or in a special `monkeypatch.py` file.

Comment: You are correct I'll add that line to my models.py file. Any idea though on why the email is saved under the last name field?

Comment: So I moved that line to models.py and the problem is now fixed. Not sure if that's what was wrong or if it was a bug that magically disappeared but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you want to reinvent the password encryption process? Generally doing this will usually be less secure than Django's native solution.

Have you considered creating a custom user model that would use a unique email (bypassing the magic in the form)?
Also, I would advise you to look into django-registration or django-allauth (I prefer all-auth). These would effectively do everything you're trying to do for you.

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth
https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration

Comment: I'm not exactly reinventing the authentication process. I'm still using the build in authentication I just extended the user profile and added a keypair and a few other stuff. I'm doing this for experimentation and practice, nothing that will go into production. It's more of a project.